# Feathers.js - get service path/route from service instance

Tags: feathersjs

Is there a way to get service path/route from the service wrapper?

Something like this:

`let myService = app.service('users');`

`myService.name === 'users'; // true`

I am trying to create new services dynamically based on existing services, like so:

```
let services = [service1, service2, service3];

services.forEach(service=>{
    app.use(`somePrefix-${service.name}`, {get: get, find:find /*etc*/});
});
```

And I need the path of the service to register for the new path.

Comment: As a solution for now, I have added the path as a property in the service setup function:

`setup(app, path) { this.path = path }`

Then I can just get it like so: `myService.path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a two ways to do this. The first, you already answere yourself: Use the [setup](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#setupapp-path) method and set `this.path = path`.

The other would be to add a [service mixin](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/application.html#mixins) which will be called whenever a service is registered.

```
app.mixins.push((service, path) => {
  // Only do this for non-prefixed services
  if(path.indexOf('somePrefix') === -1) {
    services.forEach(service => {
        app.use(`somePrefix-${path}`, {get: get, find:find /*etc*/});
    });
  }
});
```